# How can i order by id ascending?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to order data by Id, how can i do this ?

```
if($_GET["grupid"]>0){
    $DUZEN = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM siparis_ana WHERE grupid =".$_GET["grupid"];
    $rsDuzen = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error()); 
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsDuzen)) {
        $DUZEN[] = $r;
    }
}
```

i can read all data with this code which have same group id. But data aline random.

Comment: Using the `ORDER BY id ASC`

Comment: Use ORDER BY grupid ASC

Comment: I've tried but I think I'm syntax mistakes

Comment: Why is this tagged with jQuery? Note that your code is ***wide*** open to SQL injection attacks in its current form. The`mysql_` methods were deprecated a while ago. You should be using prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use mysql order clause in your query like `order by id asc`. Which you can use at the end of your query.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM siparis_ana WHERE grupid =".$_GET["grupid"]." order by id asc";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sql query should be like given below...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM siparis_ana where grupid = " . $_GET['grupid'] . " ORDER BY id asc ";
```

Comment: ah, happy to heard that

Comment: @babacan Didn't you say you tried this? What did you do differently? Update your question to show the code that got the syntax errors, so we can explain the problem.